# :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: ionic-framework

Trying to compile my project using ionic build android , I have encountered an error.

I have tried all the proposed solutions I found on questions asked in this community or other sites.

i Tried:

**delete folder npm_cache**

**remove android platform and install again**

```
ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0
OS:
Node Version: v5.5.0


ionic build android

:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\pedromiguel\.gradle\caches\2.13\classAnalysis\cache.properties (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

FAILED

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 6.6 secs

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\pedromiguel\.gradle\caches\2.13\classAnalysis\cache.properties (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
> cordova platform update android
> ionic build android
```

Comment: I do it this, but don't work, i create new projects, but dont work, but with old projects created compiled fine.

Comment: i tried many times, second time show me that [Test 2](http://pastebin.com/B1uEKH8m), third time [Test 3](http://pastebin.com/6mjWD0UT), after use `ionic build android`, but the same error, [ionic build android](http://pastebin.com/jA7eYnYf)

Comment: Have you the latest version of android sdk?

Comment: Wait, i open the Android Studio

Comment: thanks, i am update android studio, sdk and avd, and all updates show me, i tell you later